# SQL datetime LIKE select - why do I need an extra %?

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

Can someone explain to me why when I perform a `LIKE` select in SQL (T-SQL) on a `varchar` column I can do the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table
  WHERE Name LIKE 'Th%'
```

to get names beginning with `Th`, but when I do the same on a `datetime` column I need a `%` before the year, like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table
  WHERE Date LIKE '%2013%'
```

to get dates in 2013. The datetimes are stored in `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` format. I know I could use a `DATEPART` style query but I was just interested in why I need the extra `%` here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DATETIME is converted to a VARCHAR before the comparison, and there definitely is no guarantee that the conversion will be in the pattern you mention. DATETIME is not stored internally as a VARCHAR but as a FLOAT.

Comment: You can verify that with the following query: `SELECT charindex('2013',GETDATE())`

Answer (score 2):

You should stop wondering because the syntax is not useful.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Date LIKE '%2013%'
```

Will give you a full table scan because the date will be converted to a varchar when comparing. In other words, don't do it !

Use this syntax instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Date >= '2013-01-01T00:00:00'
  and Date < '2014-01-01T00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If the Date field is in timestamp:-
SELECT *
      FROM Table
      WHERE year(Date) = '2013'
```

Comment: your syntax will result in a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

The sql server converts datetime to this format (Jan 1, 1900 9:20AM.)Because of that reason We need to use an extra %.

If you want to search the records start with month Jan

you can use following query for date time

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Date LIKE 'Jan%'.
```

No need of extra '%'.

Comment: -1. Datetime will not be converted into that format. It will give slow performance. *SELECT charindex('%jan%',GETDATE())* returns 0 in my databases

Comment: Internally it will convert to that format.Please chk this link once http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: Internally it will be a float ! Never use *like* on numerics

Comment: dont use char index.Use direct query like i mentioned. SELECT *
  FROM Table
  WHERE Date LIKE 'Jan%'.   Here Date should be datetime datatype.I got results for this.

Comment: You are right, the syntax is valid. I had wildchar in my charindex which gave me the wrong result. When comparing without [conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CAST_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) the default is 0 or 100. However that is not how the data is stored. So all dates will be converted to that format before comparing crippling performance.