# Python flask mysql array addition to new table

Tags: python, mysql, flask

```
@app.route('/getnewalldaily')
def getnew_alldaily():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    created_at = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    date = created_at
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO jsontabledaily(id,code,ip,date,data) SELECT 
    id,code,ip,date,data FROM jsontable WHERE date LIKE %s""", [date])
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM jsontabledaily')
    veriler = list(cursor.fetchall())
    cursor.close()
    return render_template('/getnewalldaily.html', datas=veriler)
```

Hey.
I have a problem with python flask app using mysql.
My problem is that, I have a table which takes all data everytime. And I have another table.

Table1 : `jsondata`,
Table2 : `jsondatadaily`

I want to send data to table2 but daily. There is a field in my table whose name is 'data', data is a json array(number). I want to send another table this json array and add them in a one row. For example:
Table 1:

```
ip:1 code:1 date:28.09.2022 data: [1,2] 
ip:1 code:1 date:28.09.2022 data: [3,4]
ip:1 code:1 date:28.09.2022 data: [5,6]
ip:2 code:2 date:28.09.2022 data: [11,22]
ip:2 code:2 date:28.09.2022 data: [33,44]
```

I want them to be like this in table2 (daily table):

```
ip:1 code:1 date:28.09.2022 data: [1,2],[3,4],[5,6]...
ip:2 code:2 date:28.09.2022 data: [11,22],[33,44]...
```

These should be daily. In table 1 we have 10000 rows for example, but in table 2 we just want to see today's data.

Actually it works. I have 2 problems. First is , I can not add them to 1 row like
[1,2][3,4][5,6].... i mean for data field. Another problem is, Jsondatadaily(tablo 2) is empty. I do not know why ? Is there something wrong here ? Here is pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most likely, the LIKE query on a date field did not work. Its not a good idea! Check this answer for a better idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/19832666/995052

Comment: I changed it but still table 2 is empty. Or did I write wrong sql code?

Comment: Did you execute the query and check if it works outside your code ?

Comment: I did, it works. But table 2 is empty. I can not insert from table 1 to table 2. In the photo above u can see datas code1 .... But when i select from table 2 , in mysql , table is empty. And i want to add arrays do u know how to do it ? like [1,2],[3,4],[4,5]..